# button disabled while required fields are empty

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm using [this](https://themeforest.net/item/aero-admin-reponsive-material-design-dashboard/16283301) template for forms. For text inputs, it provides the opportunity to validate the input (simple: if it's empty, red box, if it's not, green box). However, I want my submit button (markup below) to be clickable only if all necessary fields are at least not empty.

```
<button type="submit" name="finish" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for downvoting without stating any reasons whatsoever.

Comment: Disable the button, have each input have a `onchange` event or similar and check if all the inputs are not empty, then remove the disable if so and otherwise add/keep it (*add it as a separate function*). You would also want to do the same thing on the submit event.

Comment: I haven't down-voted, but I can see why. Starting with the fact that you haven't seem to of attempted to solve the problem yourself. If you have, include your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `oninput` to immediately reflect changes in inputs and check if any input is empty.

HTML

```
    <form id="frm">
      <input type="text" name="input1" oninput="testFinish();" />
      <input type="text" name="input2" oninput="testFinish();" />
      <button type="submit" name="finish" disabled onsubmit="alert('SUBMITTED')">Finish</button>
    </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function testFinish(){
var frm = document.getElementById('frm');
if (frm['input1'].value && frm['input2'].value)
  frm['finish'].disabled = false;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahp3m13d/)

Answer (score 1):

I post here a simple demo due I don't want to dive inside the template.

The logic is simple. You need to "listen" to the input's events `change` and `keypress`, then check if it's valid (I tested the code in the last Chrome, need to check this validation API in other browsers or create your own, or use a library). If so, remove the attribute `disabled` if not, add it.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input'),
    button = document.querySelector('button');

addListenerMulti(inputs, 'keyup change', function() {
  if (valid()) {
    button.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
  else {
    button.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});

function valid() {
  var valid = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (!inputs[i].validity.valid) {
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  return valid;
}

function addListenerMulti(el, s, fn) {
  var col = el.length ? el : [el];
  var evts = s.split(' ');

  for (var k = 0; k < col.length; k++) {
    for (var i = 0, iLen = evts.length; i < iLen; i++) {
      col[k].addEventListener(evts[i], fn, false);
    }   
  }  
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" required /><br />
  <input type="text" required /><br />
  <button disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: All input fields need to not be empty, not just one.

Comment: You don't expect me to simulate all the inputs for you. The answer is only a direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on my desktop right now but I'm providing you just a basic layout what you need to do ..if you need more assistance mention in comment..don't forget the tick .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>JavaScript Can Validate Input</h1>
    <p>Please input a number between 1 and 10:</p>
    <input id="numb">
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var x, text;

        // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
        x = document.getElementById("numb").value;

        // If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 10
        if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 10) {
          text = "Input not valid";
        } else {
          text = "Input OK";
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not relevant to the question.. He wants to **disable** the button until the form will be valid.

Comment: I answered same to some other dude with my other account.

Comment: I see ..let me rephrase

Comment: He wants to disable the button so probably you need to bind listener to inputs to see if it is valid to enable the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try the bello HTML and javascript CODE:

```
<form id="my-form">
  <input type="text" name="input1" class="required abc" />
  <input type="text" name="input2" class=" abc" />
  <input type="text" name="input3" class="required abc" />
  <input type="text" name="input4" class=" abc" />
  <input type="text" name="input5" class="abc" />
  <button type="submit" name="finish" onsubmit="alert('SUBMITTED')">Finish</button>
</form>
```

Java script code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form input").blur( function(){
        var has_error = false;
        $("form input.required").each(function(){
            if($(this).val() == ''){
                $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
                has_error = true;
            }
            else{
                    $(this).css('border','');
            }
        });
        if(has_error == false){
            $("form button[name='finish']").prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else {
                $("form button[name='finish']").prop('disabled',true);
        }
    });
});
```

check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t19t2rdc/) for more info.